# Leaflet always centers map after click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I am using leaflet (vue2leaflet, for Vue.js) to render an image.
I have added some custom elements, like dragging and dropping boxes on the map, then let them be drawn by leaflet (as a rectangle leaflet object).

My aim is, to click on a rectangle and pan the map to it (centering the rectangle, we can forget the zoom in this question).

The problem: Any time, when i click on a rectangle and use the map.panTo() method, the map pans to it's center at [0,0].

How can i prevent that? It also happens, when i drag&drop a div-box at the map.

I guess that some click event could be the bug, but i couldn't find it until now.

Comment: Please post the code. See [ask].

Comment: I finally fixed it. The problem was, that i passed an initial :center - prop to my leaflet-component, which was used to pan to, on every update:center - event.

Here is the GitHub Issue, which helped me out:

https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet/issues/31

Comment: Sure, i just thought that my comment is enough, but you are right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. The problem was, that i passed an initial :center - prop to my leaflet-component, which was used to pan to, on every update:center - event. Here is the GitHub Issue, which helped me out: [GitHub](https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet/issues/31)